# How to hide times header of a timelineMonth view on Kendo UI Scheduler widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm trying to hide times header from a Kendo UI Scheduler widget but until now, I didn't achieved the results I need in my choosen type of view. I don't need times because all my events are all day events. Therefore, is there any way of not showing times such as 12:00 AM, 13:00 AM, etc...

I followed the documentation and if I put it in my script, the Scheduler doesn't show up anymore. Here're the scripts:

```
dataBinding: function(e) {
            var view = this.view();

            view.times.hide();
            view.timesHeader.hide();
        },
```

and/or

```
dataBound: function(e) {
            var tables = $(".k-scheduler-times .k-scheduler-table");

            //Required: remove only last table in dataBound when grouped
            tables = tables.last();

            var rows = tables.find("tr");

            rows.each(function() {
              $(this).children("th:last").hide();
            });
        },
```

Then, as an other alternative, I simply added this line of script into the views section:

```
minorTickCount: 0
```

All the rows with the 12:00 AM disappeared however, that made my Schedule complete obsolete because it erased all the cells of where events are showed.

Anyone ever encountered such an issue to overcome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this css:

```
.k-scheduler-timelineWeekview > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) .k-scheduler-table tr:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: it's a timelineMonth view but yes, you got it right... thanks. I also found another alternative so... to whoever may be interested in the future, just add the following line of script to your views property: majorTimeHeaderTemplate: kendo.template("")

Comment: Messing with this myself here and came upon this answer while trying to figure out how to hide them. Just to clarify: the method samureira mentions in the comment above will just leave the time headers in timeline month view blank. The boxes will still be there and be empty (which isn't great looking as you now just have random boxes for seemingly no reason, but it is dependent on your use case). Tom's answer completely hides them though :). samureira's method is much simpler if you are OK leaving the boxes in there.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was fixed with the following code:

```
 dataBound: function(e) {
   var view = this.view();
   view.datesHeader.find("tr:last").prev().hide();
   view.timesHeader.find("tr:last").prev().hide();
 }
```